# Commutivity of second functional derivatives

Tags: functional-equations

In multivariable calculus we learn that partial derivatives are commutative: i.e. $\partial _{xy}F=\partial_{yx}F$

When dealing with multiple functional derivatives this doesn't seem to be the case.

Consider the simple functional equation: $\mathcal{I}[f]=\int f(x)dx$

It would seem that if we compute the functional derivative: $\large\frac{\delta^2\mathcal{I}[f^3]}{\delta f(x_0)\delta f(x_1)}$ the same rules of commutivity that apply in multivariable calculus are not present. Depending on the order we take the two derivatives, we would either get $6[f(x_0)]$ or $ 6[f(x_1)]$.

My question is obvious: which is the proper answer? It would seem to me that the derivative with respect to $f(x_1)$ would be computed last and thus the ladder of the two would be correct.

Comment: I'm not clear on the notation, but failure of "shape" derivatives to commute is more a consequence of dependence (lack of independence) between the quantities being varied.  Partial derivatives commute only when the variable *not* being differentiated with respect to is held constant.  So I'd be curious if this condition of independence is met by your second order "functional derivative".

Comment: The definition of the functional derivative that my book has is $\frac{\delta H[f(y)]}{\delta f(x)}=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon}\huge( \normalsize H[f(y)+\epsilon \delta(y-x)]-H[f(y)] \huge)$ from this you can see how I got the two different answers that I posted. Is the term "functional derivative" that my book is using an incorrect term?